# How do i get the download link for pdf in a document library of microsoft sharepoint using microsoft graph api?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I am using sharepoint extension which redirects to my localhost webapp that will display the pdf. The pdf first will be downloaded from the link provided from the sharepoint extension. The sharepoint site already had a document library named 'abc' and using this endpoint `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}%2c{webId}/drive/items/{itemId}`, the pdf gets downloaded. But i added a new document library named `xyz` inside the same site but it returns resource not found. I am not able to solve this issue. Can someone help?

So, for this i looked into the microsoft graph v1 and made a little change to the api to see the list which is like this `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}%2c{webId}/lists/{listId}/items/{itemId}` but i get the response

```
error : {
        "code": "invalidRequest",
        "message": "Provided list item identifer is not in an allowed format",
       "innerError" :{...}
}
```